# Google cloud sql console hangs

Tags: google-cloud-sql

since the last week I am facing troubles entering into my **google cloud sql** settings in *Google Cloud* Platform portal. it hangs.
Might be someone faced the same issue, please help !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly where does this happen? after you click what? also, could you open the developer's console (Ctrl + Shift + J in chrome) and check if there are any errors there?

Comment: It happens when I try open link https://console.cloud.google.com/sql?project=mate-climate

Comment: Thans for your Ctrl + Shift + J advice, it unfolds some details, but I dont know how it can help: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Uncaught CustomError: Error in protected function: Failure: Ob`ДЕНЬ

Comment: Screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/zvW0AhADshGPE

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a problem with our Russian translation which is causing this. It should be fixed soon, but as a temporary workaround you can switch to English in the Cloud Console settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, switching to English has solved the problem